# New IE Update Breaks Typical Cookie Detection Methods - What To Do Now?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

This recent update to IE (affects all versions) rewrites cookies stored with a random 8-digit alpha numeric name, making most typical cookie detection methods useless:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx

Has anyone encountered this, and if so, what did you do to overcome this? Unfortunately we cannot ignore our IE users, as much as I wish that could be a solution :)

UPDATE: I tagged this with JQuery as it affects JQuery's cookie plugin, which popular scripts like the JQuery UI Tabs uses to "remember" tab positions.

Comment: But: since when did IE stop sending the cookies to the server over HTTP? I.e. since when did you *have* to load cookies in pure JS? I imagine, as ugly as you might find it, that converting the cookie on the server into an JS/JSON object would work? Of course if the user doesn't want to send that cookie then it would fail, but in that case I think not doing something the user actively does not want is better behaviour than doing it anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking about?  Cookies are completely unchanged when accessed from javascript in the web page or from the server when sent with the HTTP request.  The only thing I've seen that changed is that the filenames of cookies stored in the IE9 content directory have changed and are now more random (making it harder for an attacker to grab one).  There is no reason I know of to directly access those files from any web application.  If you have such a reason, please clarify.

Comment: If in your code you're doing something like (pseudocode):

if cookiename.domain.com exists
do this

How would I find the cookie I'm looking for if the cookie name is now a randomly generated set of numbers and letters?

Comment: Change the way you work and test to see whether something exists *within* the cookie that gets sent. If you are trying to do something based on a cookie being set from a different site then you might be out of luck.

Comment: Blair, You might be right if this was a case of reading a cookie set by a different site, but in our case it's reading the cookies' name itself that we set programmatically. Sorry I didn't clarify this in my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this question with JQuery (and this change is entirely transparent to JQuery and JavaScript), I think you may be confused about what exactly changed.

As noted in my blog post, the recent code change affects neither how cookies are sent, nor the APIs that are properly used locally to enumerate over the cookies (InternetGetCookie and FindFirstURLCacheEntry). Any code that was relying upon the name of the text file was already fragile, as the name of those files was never guaranteed, and there were already cases where the filename would be entirely randomized.

Comment: Eric, I forgot to include the fact that in our case, we're encountering this issue with JQuery's Cookie where it reads the name of the cookie... Sorry for any confusion. I do take exception with your assertion that "relying upon the name of the cookie was fragile and never guaranteed" - we're setting the cookie's name programmatically, so how is that never guaranteed? Reading other site's cookies, sure - reading your own - I think not.